# How to plot curve smoothly in grafana with Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a Grafana dashboard which plot the data of Premethus/node-exportor. But the line looks like a lot of mountain peaks, how do I set the metrics so that the line looks smooth?

e.g. to get cpu utility, the current metrics I use is below. How to make the curve show as a line:
 
100 - avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",project="$project"}[5m])) * 100

it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this result. What is the time range of it?

Comment: it is 6 hours. I found if I change irate to rate, the plot looks smoother. but it still does not look like the plot I saw from aws or gcp's monitoring service, they must do something to make the plot smoother.

Comment: Prometheus documentation: irate should only be used when graphing volatile, fast-moving counters. Use rate for alerts and slow-moving counters, as brief changes in the rate can reset the FOR clause and graphs consisting entirely of rare spikes are hard to read.

Comment: yeah, changing irate to rate resolved the issue partially, if it is still not smooth, then maybe that means the cpu itself is not smooth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may smooth the plot be increasing the observed time span that you use for averaging

```
100 - avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",project="$project"}[<time_span>])) * 100
```

in your case time_span=5m try to increase it to time_span=30m